# Fast reverse lookup of indexed elements

Tags: java

My problem is trying to improve performance in a case of a reverse lookup in an index. I have an ordered list of Objects that has to be conceptually split into categories. The index for where each category start is retrieved when the list is created and needs to be stored. The lookup comes later, when I give an index of the ordered list and need to know to which category it belongs.

In my current approach I have two ordered lists: one with elements and another one with the indexes to the categories.

```
List<Object> data = { "df", "sdfgbh", "sgdadF", "dfdF", "dFADF", "adfadf", "Dafadf", "dafadf", "654654", "sfgsfgsfg", "ethdgh", "fgnfghfgh", "fghsdfgh", "54654", ...up to 1000 }

List<Integer> categories = { 50, 146, 222, 345, 475, 610, 824, 968 }
```

When trying to find the category for index i, the algorithm has performance O(n)

```
public int categoryIndex(int position) {
 for (Integer i: categories){
   if (i > position) return i;  
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Is there any other approach to this problem that has better performance than Binary Search?

Comment: If your category list dynamic ? If not, you could calculate for all your data entries the corresponding category and store those couples into an array. A custom index if you want. You will got a O(n) lookup time for building the index, but a O(i) when getting an element category.

Comment: categoryIndex is rather indifferent to the data list. You really just need to binary search this.

Comment: @OlivierH That would create another array of 1000+ elements in memory, not very efficient. My Objects are not Strings, just changed it for the example.

Comment: @EfEs is your list of objects, some object that you have control to change? If so you can just put a reference to the relevant category in that object

Comment: @EfEs Yes, but a simple array of references. Not a big deal nowadays. You could also store reference to category directly on element object.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from lengthening your `data` list and doing a direct index lookup (this would cost only 1 pointer of memory per element, so only about 4k for a list of 1000 elements - feasible at least), a binary search would at least be `O(log(n))` time.